# Nivéis de Zoom API Google Maps

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Alguém sabe dizer se tem como setar o nivél maximo de zoom e o nivél minimo na API do Google Maps?

Quando você deixa no zoom minimo os hemisferios se repetem e não quero que o usuário veja isso.

Ex de pontos repetidos: https://www.google.com/maps/@32.7903114,79.5768393,2z

Quero evitar exatamente isso, a duplicidade de locais, e o que inicialmente pensei foi, limitar o zoom do usuário. Definir o zoom min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra quem tiver interesse,

Na documentação do Google Maps, existe uma propriedade chamada MinZoon. Basta você setar o valor minimo.

Exemplo:

```
    mapOptions = {
                            zoom: zoom,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.8097, -98.5553),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                            mapTypeControl: false,
                            panControl: false,
                            disableDefaultUI: true,
                            navigationControl: false,
                            streetViewControl: false,
                            scrollwheel: false,
                            zoomControl: true,
                            minZoom: 2
 };
```